# regular expression - find numbers after symbol

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use the below regular expressions to find any numbers after the '|' operator to work with a few example strings below. The issue is with the default regex where i cant seem to combine the numerical_regex with the Lookbehind.

```
'xxx -> 31223.1 | xxx -> 1.1'.    to get 1.1

'0 | 1'     to get 1

numeric_regex = ''' 
                [-+]?                    # pos or neg
                (?: (?: \d* \. \d+ ) |   # float (ie .1 and 1.1)
                (?: \d+ \.? ) )          # int (with trailing periods ie 1.)
            '''

default_regex = f'''
                (? <= \|).               # after but not including |
                {numeric_regex}          # all digits
                + $                      # end of the string
            '''
```

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Hi Tommy, did either of the answers help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Following is a small program for your problem statement

```
import re

regex = r"\|.*?[\-\+]?(\d+\.\d+|\d+\.?|\.\d+)"

test_str = ("xxx -> 31223.1 | xxx -> 1.1\n"
    "0|1\n"
    "0|abc 1.\n"
    "0|.1\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

regex which u are looking for is

> regex = r"\|.*?[-+]?(\d+.\d+|\d+.?|.\d+)"

tested only few scenarios, hope that it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work in a way. Can i ask what what wrong with my attempt? 

I was hoping to be able to return the number from re.complie(default_regex).group().

Also, if possible, do you think this can be done using the formatted string? i have other regexs that need to use the numeric_regex as part of another regex.

Answer (score 0):

You main issue is that you are introducing spaces where they should not be even when using `re.X` or `re.VERBOSE` flags. You cannot separate the characters that form a lookbehind construct. You should also keep quantifiers with the quantified subpatterns.

Also, you do not need a lookbehind here, just *capture* your number with a capturing group and then access it using `match.group(1)`.

See [full Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZGgFEp), and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5mr7J/2):

```
import re
numeric_regex = r'''
                [-+]?                    # pos or neg
                (?:
                  \d*\.\d+               # float (ie .1 and 1.1)
                  | 
                  \d+ \.?                # int (with trailing periods ie 1.)
                )'''

default_regex = rf'''
                .*                       # Match as many chars as possible (use with re.S)
                \|.*?                    #  | and 0+ chars as few as possible
                ({numeric_regex})        # Capturing group: all digits
                $                        # end of the string
'''
m = re.search(default_regex, "xxx -> 31223.1 | xxx 1.1", re.S | re.VERBOSE)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => 1.1
```

Note the `(...)` in the `default_regex`. In the `numeric_regex`, that we might want to re-use, a non-capturing group is used, `(?:...)` because all we need from it is to group two alternatives here.

The main regex scheme is now `.*\|.*?({numeric_regex})$`, that is, match `|`, 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, then the numeric part is captured into Group 1 and then `$` asserts the position at the end of the string. Due to the first `.*`, you will get the rightmost for `|` (and subsequent patterns) match.

Comment: thanks for the answer.

i dont think this works for the case given though,  "xxx -> 31223.1 | xxx 1.1" ?

Comment: @Tommy For xxx, if you need to match any text, just use `.*?`, I  updated the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Just for clarification, why do we need to extract by group?

Comment: @Tommy We need a group because the pattern before it can be of variable length, and Python `re` does not support unknown length patterns in lookbehinds.

Comment: Makes sense. There is one more case i cant seem to figure out, when we have multiple '|" operators. How would this be handled? I forgot to mention, it would have to find the last operator. Thanks again

'  30  ->  2  |  4  ->  3.2  |0  '

Comment: @Tommy Add `.*` at the start. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5mr7J/3)